# How to check for <Suspense> components from a chrome extension tool?

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

I am working on a tool in the form of a chrome extension that checks the timing metrics for components wrapped in the Suspense component to check how long they were suspense for. Here's an example of what I am referring to.

```
<Suspense placeholder={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
  <Component />
</Suspense>
```

However, I am having trouble checking for specific component names.
Was wondering if someone could suggest an approach or a method of retrieving component names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out after digging a while in Reacts fibre tree (by console logging `document.getElementById('root')._reactRootContainer._internalRoot.current` in the browser, also make sure your root is called "root") that you are able to distinguish Suspense components by their tag. Eventually led me to this link:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cbbc2b6c4d0d8519145560bd8183ecde55168b12/packages/shared/ReactWorkTags.js#L34

and I was able to console.log Suspense components by search tag === 13.